# Sequelize: Multiple associations between two same tables

Tags: sequelize.js

If I have two tables: users and articles
and set the following relationships:

```
user.hasMany(articles, {as: 'author'})
user.hasMany(articles, {as: 'owner'})
user.belongsToMany(articles, {through: 'article_contributors'})
article.belongsToMany(user, {through: 'article_contributors'})
```

how would I set the 'owner' of an article?

I tried:

```
user.addArticle(article, {as: 'owner'});
```

but that set the relation in the article_contributors table.

Answer (score 0):

update: found the solution. I had to call user.addOwner(path).